# Access svn logs using tortoisesvn .svn folder

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

I'm using [RiouxSVN](https://riouxsvn.com) as the SVN Server.I deleted my project repository from the svn server(RiouxSVN) about week ago.before I delete the repository I took a backup of my project.Inside that backup folder there is an hidden folder called ".svn". Inside that .svn folder there are lots of files.

now what I need is I want to access my previous logs.Since I do not have any repository in SVN Server, can I do that using my backup folder( using that .svn hidden file or any other method)

### My svn client version information.

- TortoiseSVN 1.7.7, Build 22907 - 32 Bit , 2012/05/15 12:16:05
- Subversion 1.7.5,
- apr 1.4.6
- apr-utils 1.3.12
- neon 0.29.6
- OpenSSL 1.0.1c 10 May 2012
- zlib 1.2.7

Thanks.

Comment: How did you create your backup? By svnrdump? If you have just created a copy of local files from your working copy (implied by mentioning .svn folder), I think metadata is gone.

Answer (score 2):

You have [a working copy of your repository](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.basic.version-control-basics.html#svn.basic.working-copy) only. If you don't have a backup of the [actual repository](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.basic.version-control-basics.html#svn.basic.repository) then you are out of luck -- no revision history. I can suggest contacting your svn hoster to ask whether they have a backup of the deleted repository on their side.

Answer (score 1):

That `.svn` is not like git's `.git` folder. That `.git` folder is your Git repository and the entire history. However, that `.svn` folder merely contains data to help Subversion track your working copy. That `.svn` directory contains:

- A base of all the files in your working directory. This allows Subversion to be able to give you basic information about changes (when you do a Status or a Diff) without having to ping the server.
- Basic information about your checkout including who did it, what revision you're at, the URL of your server. This way, you don't have to keep giving this information over and over again every time you do a Subversion command.
- Information about the properties on those files.

There is no information about older revisions, so you can't find anything via the `svn log` command.

Comment: This is not true. My \.svn\pristine folder contains many .svn-base files which are older revisions of existing files. Unfortunately the file names are random strings, not the original file names.

Answer (score 1):

In general, no...the .svn folder contains no history information. Depending on what exactly you are trying to do, you *may* be lucky, since you are using TortoiseSVN. TortoiseSVN keeps a cache of log messages, so if you just try a "show log" on your backup, it *may* prompt you to view the log offline, and you *may* see the information you need. You will not be able to examine or retrieve anything from those past states, though, just the log messages.